# What happens to a dependency defined in a root project in a subproject in gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, dependency-management

I have a gradle project with several subprojects. I have defined several dependencies with version numbers in the root project but not all subprojects use all of these dependencies.

```
root
- build.gradle
    - compile 'math:math:1.0.0'
- settings.gradle
    - include 'messages'
    - include 'message-handler'
\ messages
    - build.gradle
        - //no math
\ message-handler
    - build.gradle
        - compile 'math:math'
```

Will my artifact of the messages project contain a dependency on the math library?

In other words, if I make a separate project that depends on the messages artifact from a nexus repository, would my dependency tree show the math library for this new project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - your messages project artifact will contain a dependency on the math library.

According to [Gradle Documentation](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html#sec:examples):

> For most multi-project builds, there is some configuration which is
>   common to all projects. In our sample, we will define this common
>   configuration in the root project, using a technique called
>   configuration injection. Here, the root project is like a container
>   and the subprojects method iterates over the elements of this
>   container - the projects in this instance - and injects the specified
>   configuration

In other words, every configuration which is included in the root project will hold for all the sub-projects.